# asp.net mvc 5 Вывод нескольких полей объекта в одну ячейку таблицы

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Имеется следующая проблема:
Есть таблица заказы, в которой есть заказанное изделие, покупатель, сотрудник, цена и кол-во. для изделия и покупателя надо вывести только свойство `Name`, поэтому проблем нет, но для сотрудника хочу вывести свойства `Surname`, `Name` и `Patronymic`

Написал такой код, но он не выводит вообще ничего

```
@model IEnumerable<Bakery.Models.Order>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Список заказов";
}

<h2>Список заказов</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Добавить", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Count)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.Display(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.Employee.Surname, item.Employee.Name, item.Employee.Patronymic))
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Сам класс заказа

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Bakery.Models
{
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {

    }

    public Order(Employee employee, Product product, Customer customer, Double count, Double price)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Employee = employee;
        Product = product;
        Customer = customer;
        Count = count;
        Price = price;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Код
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Сотрудник
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Сотрудник")]
    [Required]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid? EmployeeId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Изделие
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Изделие")]
    [Required]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid? ProductId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Заказчик
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Покупатель")]
    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid? CustomerId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Количество заказанных изделий
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Количество изделий (шт.)")]
    [Required]
    [Range(1, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Количество не может быть меньше 1")]
    public double Count { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Цена
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Цена (руб.)")]
    [Required]
    [Range(0.1, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Цена не может быть меньше 0.1")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: конечно он не выводит ничего, у вас же контроллера нет

Comment: контроллер есть, и выводит все, кроме вот этого столбца

Comment: так у вас строка неправильная. Что это должно делать? `@Html.Display(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.Employee.Surname, item.Employee.Name, item.Employee.Patronymic))` пробовали заменить на `@string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.Employee.Surname, item.Employee.Name, item.Employee.Patronymic)`?

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо. помогло

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас строка неправильная.

```
@Html.Display(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.Employee.Surname, item.Employee.Name, item.Employee.Patronymic))
```

замените на

```
@string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.Employee.Surname, item.Employee.Name, item.Employee.Patronymic)
```